# How do you set colors for term?

Tags: colors, term

I want to run `tmux` in emacs. I checked that it works in `term`, but default colors are awfully hard to read:
[image]

How can they be changed to a sensible setting from `.emacs` file?

Comment: I found that themes like `solarized` and `zenburn` does change `term` colurs, but my favorite `wombat` theme does nothing to them. So it is possible to `(load-theme 'zenburn) (load-theme 'wombat)` for changing to sensible term colors, but that also changes font in a way I don't like.

Answer (score 4):

Since in `zenburn` theme terminal colors look good I added the following lines in my `.emacs`:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces

 '(term-color-black ((t (:foreground "#3F3F3F" :background "#2B2B2B"))))
 '(term-color-red ((t (:foreground "#AC7373" :background "#8C5353"))))
 '(term-color-green ((t (:foreground "#7F9F7F" :background "#9FC59F"))))
 '(term-color-yellow ((t (:foreground "#DFAF8F" :background "#9FC59F"))))
 '(term-color-blue ((t (:foreground "#7CB8BB" :background "#4C7073"))))
 '(term-color-magenta ((t (:foreground "#DC8CC3" :background "#CC9393"))))
 '(term-color-cyan ((t (:foreground "#93E0E3" :background "#8CD0D3"))))
 '(term-color-white ((t (:foreground "#DCDCCC" :background "#656555"))))

 '(term-default-fg-color ((t (:inherit term-color-white))))
 '(term-default-bg-color ((t (:inherit term-color-black))))

 )
```

Comment: `M-x customize-group RET term RET`

Comment: How about the bold colors?

Comment: @Gauthier I think you should check the `~/.Xresources` file for that.